# I am working Acc Controller created by me not Account controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorize

I have my own acc controller instead of default Account controller in asp.net mvc with my own database in mysql.How to authorize some action method?If i put [Authorize] its demanding login ,but after login if I click that authorized action method its still redirecting login while I already logged in.please help...

Comment: Hi Sourav2903, you should take a look at [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question/try again. You've not given enough information to receive proper help.

Answer (score 0):

[Role based Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles)

Please have a look into the linke hope your query will be resolve.